# Target runtime JBoss v4.2 is not defined

Tags: eclipse-juno, jboss-4.2.x

I have imported a project and got the error "Target runtime JBoss v4.2 is not defined".
I have added the JBoss 4.2 Runtime library.  However, the error is still there.

In my Java Build Path, I have the followling libraries added already.

[image]

What other libraries do I miss to add?

Answer (score 25):

Have found the solution from net.

```
Right click on your project -> "Properties" -> "Project Facets" -> "runtimes" ->
uncheck your JBoss v4.2 and v5.0 check the new Jboss
```

But for my case, "uncheck JBoss 4.2 and check JBoss v4.2" for the last step.

Comment: Yes it worked for me too.This happens if you have more than one server configured.It takes the first one

Answer (score 1):

```
        Right click on java project -> build path -> configure build path ->
 libreries -> add external jars or add jars -> browse jboss client jar -> applay -> ok
```

i think this process may help you, i had followed this process, it was working for me.